# Basic Java Vending Machine Program

Tags: java

I am making a vending machine program and I'm not sure whats wrong

VendingMachine.java:

public class VendingMachine {

```
int canCount;
int tokenCount;

public VendingMachine()
{
    canCount = 0;
    tokenCount = 0;
}
public VendingMachine(int initialCans, int initialTokens)
{
    canCount = initialCans;
    tokenCount = initialTokens;
}
public void fillUp(int cans) 
    {
    canCount += cans;   
    }
public void insertToken()
{
    tokenCount -= tokenCount;
    canCount -= canCount;
}
public double getCanCount()
{
    return canCount;
}
public double getTokenCount()
{
    return tokenCount;
}
```

}

VendingMachineTester.java:

```
public class VendingMachineTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VendingMachine machine = new VendingMachine(5, 5);
        machine.fillUp(10); // Fill up with ten cans
        machine.insertToken();
        machine.insertToken();
        System.out.print("Token count: ");
        System.out.println(machine.getTokenCount());
        System.out.println("Expected: 7");
        System.out.print("Can count: ");
        System.out.println(machine.getCanCount());
        System.out.println("Expected: 13");
    }
}
```

When I run it it gives me this:

```
Token count: 0.0
Expected: 7
Can count: 0.0
Expected: 13
```

I am just wondering why it is giving me zeros and not my expected values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time to learn to debug. Most IDE's have debugging capability where you can watch the state of your variables as your program runs -- you would do well to try these out and this way isolate your error.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void fillUp(int cans)    {
    canCount += canCount;   
}
```

Since canCount starts as 0, you are always adding 0 to 0 with this method, and `0 + 0` will always equal 0. Instead add the parameter to canCount: `canCount += cans;`

In the future though, it's time that you learn to debug. Most IDE's have debugging capability where you can watch the state of your variables as your program runs -- you would do well to try these out and this way isolate your error.

Note also that canCount should be an int, not a double, since ints are more accurate, and it is unlikely that you'll need to deal with a fractional number of cans.

Edit, your insertToken method will 0 any and all canCounts -- look at your logic to see why. You're subtracting canCount from canCount. So if canCount == 10, after this method 10 - 10 will equal 0.

Comment: @Abell 1. be specific about what changes you've done, by showing the latest code as an edit to your question, and 2) be specific about how it's malfunctioning since "not working" doesn't tell us much. Also show the latest output in your edit to your question.

Comment: Fixed! thank you everyone! This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow. Thanks for not tearing me apart